# Variable in place for x does't work in transit.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using **[transit.js](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)** and i have the following lines of code:

```
var axis = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
axis = genXY(axis);

if($(this).hasClass(btn_className)) {       
    $(this).transition({ axis : '100px' } , function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).transition({ axis :  0 , duration : 2000 });
    })  

}
```

The genXY function is below:

```
var xy = ['x' , 'y'];

function genXY(no) {
    return xy[no];
}
```

now i ran the below simple test on a single element(in my devTools):

```
var axis = x;
$('.gridbox .large').eq(2).transition({ x : "100px" });
```

The above line of code works perfect , I.E. it transitions the element by `100px`
 , but now if i replace the x with axis , which is actually a variable which indeed is x , now the code looks like below:

```
var axis = x;
$('.gridbox .large').eq(2).transition({ axis : "100px" });
```

The above line does't work . Why does it now work ? afterall axis is x itself , can anybody explain ?

Comment: `var axis = x;` in your code evaluates to `var axis = undefined`. I believe that you meant to type `var axis = "x";`. This doesn't matter with respect to why you cannot use `{ axis : "100px" }` to replace `{ x : "100px" }`, but I wanted to mention it to help with debugging later on.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are putting a key to a object which can't be done like that:

```
var axis = x;
$('.gridbox .large').eq(2)
             .transition({ axis : "100px" }); // <----see the object { axis : "100px" }
```

if you try putting a var name in place of key in the object literal, that doesn't refer to the value of it but it sets a new `key:value` in the object. In ES5 and earlier, you cannot use a variable as a property name inside an object literal.

So, what can be done:

```
var obj   = {}, // a new object creation
    axis  = x;  // a reference to the x

obj[axis] = '100px'; // now it results in {x:"100px"}

$('.gridbox .large').eq(2)
             .transition(obj); // <---put the object here
```

Comment: thanks for the fantastic explanation , but i still don't get it ! , can you break it down a bit ? i mean this part `if you try putting a var name in place of key in the object literal, that doesn't refer to the value of it but it sets a new key:value in the object. In ES5 and earlier, you cannot use a variable as a property name inside an object literal.`

Comment: @Jai `axis  = x;` in your code should be `axis  = 'x';`

Comment: @DaveF you are right but that could be another variable referring some other value but for sure that has to be `"x"`.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines mean the same thing (quotes are optional):

```
var obj = { x: '100px' };
var obj = { 'x': '100px' };
```

So in the following line you weren't really using a variable, but defining a property name of `x`.

```
$('.gridbox .large').eq(2).transition({ x : "100px" });
```

To solve your problem, you could define an empty object and add a dynamic property name to it, and then pass the object as an argument.

```
var axis = 'x';
var obj = {};
obj[ axis ] = '100px';
$('.gridbox .large').eq(2).transition(obj);
```

Also note that you must use the `[]` syntax for adding variable (dynamic) property names as opposed to the dot syntax. The following example will add a property named `axis` instead of `x`.

```
obj.axis = '100px';
```

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript is the specification for the language that JavaScript implements.

If you look at section "11.1.5 Object Initialiser" of the [the 5th edition of the ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf), it defines the object literal syntax that is used to create an object.

Let's take a look at how `{ axis: "100px" }` is evaluated according to the specification:

*ObjectLiteral* => { *PropertyNameAndValueList* } => { *PropertyName* : *AssignmentExpression*  }
=> { *IdentifierName* : *AssignmentExpression* }

For *IdentifierName* it states: "Return the String value containing the same sequence of characters as the IdentifierName". In other words, `{ axis: "100px" }` is the same as `{ "axis": "100px" }`, which is not the same as `{ x: "100px" }` and `{ "x": "100px" }`. In other words, an unquoted property name in an object literal becomes the string version of the name, not the variable value. This is why you cannot replace `{ x: "100px" }` with `{ axis: "100px" }` because they aren't the same.

It was suggested that you use the following code:

```
var axis = "x";
var obj = {};
obj[ axis ] = "100px";
```

This was so that the variable value of 'axis' gets used, because `obj[axis] = "100px"` is the same as `obj["x"] = "100px"`, which is the same as `{ x: "100px" }` and `{ "x": "100px" }`.